# Black screen on wc3 roc startup

Tags: 11.04, wine, playonlinux

I ran `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` and then downloaded warcraft III via the downloader client I've got on battle.net I installed it and everything went as normal.

But when I lunched wc3 for the first time I only got a black screen, I heard sound from a video explaining why it was called roc (story). The screen resolution was set to 800*600  after I launched the program, (I had to open `nvidia-x-server-settings` and set it back to normal (1355*768)).

**Info**

- Asus [1201n](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=sZ0sI6WqjnCHGFta)
- Warcraft III 1.21b ROC
- Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit

It works great under windows 7 32-bit

**Update**

I did as Roland Taylor said and it worked! I went in to the video settings inside wc3 and set it to 1366*768 and then I disabled the "emulate desktop" inside wine. now it works in fullscreen! awesome, thanks!

Now I just hope the same thing works on Frozen throne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot give you any sure solution for the video not playing, since this is probably a bug in WINE. You could try running the game using a newer WINE version (I will update my answer a bit later) in PlayOnLinux.

To fix the problem of the game resizing your screen, you need to set WINE (in PlayOnLinux's "bottle") to use a virtual desktop.
To do this:

- Click the "Configure This Application" button.

[image]
- When the configuration window opens, go to the graphics tab.
- Tick "Emulate a virtual desktop"
- Click okay to apply the settings

[image]

- Click close all in PlayOnLinux (with the application selected)

[image]

- When you run the game again, it should start in a window :)!